# Switch Nav Icons without loading

Tags: jquery

I have two navigation tabs, In 1st tab if I make any changes and when I press another icon I go to a new tab and when I go back to my previous tab my changes are removed. Is there any way I can do so that they wont refresh when switching from one navigation tab to another navigation tab but have its changes present?

On click I'm loading a page, I think I should not load but just switch. How can I switch without loading?

```
if(id == "adminSlides" ){
adminScreen.ctl.loadContent(id, true);
                        }
else if(id == "videoSlides" )
{
adminScreen.ctl.loadContent(id, true);
                        }

$('*').click(function(){
    if(this.id == "adminSlides"){
        adminScreen.ctl.loadContent("adminSlides",true);
    }
    else if(this.id == "videoSlides"){
        adminScreen.ctl.loadContent("adminVideos", true);
    } 
});
```